# iOS - resize UITableView height programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, resize, frame

I'm having a problem trying to programmatically resize the height of a `UITableView` hosted within a `UIViewController`, using iOS5 and Storyboards.  The VC displays a master/detail record style with the `UITableView` displaying the detail records.  Depending on the type of master record shown, a set of buttons may be needed at the foot of the screen.  If the buttons are not needed then I want the `UITableView` to extend it's height to take advantage of the space available.  I'm using the following code :

```
CGRect tableFrame = [tableListView frame];
if (blnApprovalRec == YES)
    tableFrame.size.height = 127;
else
    tableFrame.size.height = 170;
[tableListView setFrame:tableFrame];
```

This code is called whenever the master record changes, including when the screen first loads in `viewDidLoad`.  The problem is that when the VC loads, the `UITableView` doesn't paint using the size specified - it just paints with the default size from IB.  Once the user changes the master record so the table is reloaded then everything works fine and the size changes as required.  I've tried forcing a repaint using `setNeedsDisplay`, `setNeedsLayout` and `reloadData` but none of these worked.

Comment: In which method are you calling the above code?

Comment: Is this code placed in a method like viewDidLoad?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> The problem is that when the VC loads, the UITableView doesn't paint using the size specified

This happens, when table view is loaded, but it's UI is not getting refreshed. Please verify if you have forcefully called in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear.

Hopefully your this code is in seperate method:

```
CGRect tableFrame = [tableListView frame];
if (blnApprovalRec == YES)
   tableFrame.size.height = 127; 
else
   tableFrame.size.height = 170; 
[tableListView setFrame:tableFrame];
```

When the view appear initially, you may have the default selected value from master record.
You can set that value/instance in calling function in viewWillAppear.

Can you show method name and code for, how you are calling above snippets of code forcefully?

Comment: Many thanks Ankit, I was calling the code in viewDidLoad which I guess  meant the control hadn't fully loaded.  I moved my code to viewWillAppear and all now works :-).

Answer (score 5):

You can resize UITableView programmatically but you need to create UITableView programmatically too. Don't use Storyboard.

Comment: Yes, as far as I understand, this is correct. You have to programmatically create the table view to resize it.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Shockingly, you still can't do this with storyboards in Xcode 6.3

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, just needed to move the code from

```
   - (void) viewDidLoad
```

to

```
   - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

Answer (score 2):

This is tricky, its hard to resize things like this dynamically.

i would try "setNeedsLayout" And "setNeedsDisplay" for your table, and your screen to force a redraw.

Other than that, I would storyboard it to the minimum size and use code to expand it.

Generally apple doesn't like us doing this, your buttons should be drawn over the top of the view inside another view, if thats possible.

Sorry I can't be more precise but I have solved all these issues by mucking around and with hacks, and giving up on resizing things and doing re-designs. Please let me know how you go though :)

Comment: Not sure why is it "tricky" to resize a view dynamically? Where does Apple say that they don't want developers resize views? Why would you draw buttons over a tableview?

Comment: Well, you are following the docs and using setFrame aren't you? I am saying that following the docs has not worked for me yet when dynamially resizing. Drawing views over the top of other views is how I have fudged buttons onto tableviews in the past. But the real solution was to use navigation and tab bar controllers as well as tableviews - I had to do that to avoid the need to dynamically resize and move things around.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are setting the frame after the table has loaded.

Which method do you call that code in?